# Spring Cassandra Custom Repository for TTL Save

Tags: spring, cassandra

I'm trying use a custom repository to save an entity with a TTL (Time to Live) value. I've have done a lot of searching and read the docs online, but I'm still getting an exception.

Any help gratefully appreciated.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property saveWithTTL found for type Task!
```

The snippets are as follows:

Task (the entity):

```
@Table
public class Task {
    @PrimaryKeyColumn(ordinal = 0, type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
    private String uuid;

    private Type type;
    private Status status;
    private String parentId;

    private String body;

}
```

CassandraDbConfig:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:cassandra.properties")
@EnableCassandraRepositories(repositoryBaseClass = TTLRepositoryCustomImpl.class)
public class CassandraDbConfig extends DefaultCassandraConfig {

}
```

TTLRepositoryCustom:

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface TTLRepositoryCustom<T> extends CassandraRepository<T> {

    T saveWithTTL(T entity, Integer ttl);
}
```

TTLRepositoryCustomImpl:

```
public class TTLRepositoryCustomImpl<T> extends SimpleCassandraRepository<T, MapId>implements TTLRepositoryCustom<T> {

    public TTLRepositoryCustomImpl(final CassandraEntityInformation<T, MapId> metadata,
            final CassandraOperations operations) {
        super(metadata, operations);
    }

    @Override
    public T saveWithTTL(T entity, Integer ttl) {
        WriteOptions options = new WriteOptions();
        options.setTtl(ttl);
        return operations.insert(entity, options);
    }
}
```

TaskDbRepository:

```
@Repository
public interface TaskDbRepository extends TTLRepositoryCustom<Task> {

}
```

Full stack trace:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property saveWithTTL found for type Task!
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:77)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:329)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:309)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:272)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:243)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:76)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:247)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.buildTree(PartTree.java:398)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:378)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:86)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.query.PartTreeCassandraQuery.<init>(PartTreeCassandraQuery.java:47)
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.repository.support.CassandraRepositoryFactory$CassandraQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(CassandraRepositoryFactory.java:163)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:436)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:221)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this in a spring boot application inside a service class (with other 'normal' cassandra repo in place in the application), TTL will be in seconds, I know you are asking for a complete TTL-repo implementation, but this can be handy if you want just to save that with TTL.

```
@Autowired
private CassandraOperations cassandraOperations;

private void saveWithTTL(Task task)
{
    String cql = "insert into task (uuid, body) values ('"+task.getUuid()+"', "+task.getBody()+") USING TTL 86400;";
    cassandraOperations.execute(cql);
}
```